# Magento 2 Inventory and Stock Status

Tags: magento2, inventory, out-of-stock, stock-status

I'm trying to figure out why when the inventory quantity of a product reaches 0, the `stock_status` for the product is still `In Stock`. This happens after reindex as well. The only way to get the product stock_status on `Out of stock` is to save the store configuration from `Catalog->Inventory` section. 
 Does anyone know the reason.
Magento version currently used is 2.2.2

EDIT:

I update with stock configuration
[image]

Product settings

[image]

Comment: What is your "manage stock" settting on the product? it must be set to yes

Comment: @PhilippSander of course it is.

Comment: then you need to provide us more information. send us a screenshot of the inventory settings on the product

Comment: @PhilippSander I edited my question with the screenshot

Comment: those are not the advanced invetory settings on the product... those are oyur system configuration settings

Comment: @PhilippSander I attached both